# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse Timeout issue when running from scheduled task on a server

Tags: vb.net, salesforce, httpwebrequest, scheduled-tasks

Currently i have a .NET application the logs into SalesForce using their API. From here I query an object to pull report information and build a URL that will export me a file. The code is as such.

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse
Dim stream as Stream
request = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "GET"
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "sid=" & header.sessionId)
response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
stream = response.GetResponseStream()
```

My header.sessionId above is SalesForce Session Header which captures my session for a successful login.

This application works successfully when testing locally, or running on the production server (in Visual Studio 2010). I've set this up to run as a scheduled task which is causing the problems. The task is set up to run as the admin account on the server and works if kicked off manually (right click task -> Run) or staying connected to the server during the run time. If i disconnect from the server and the task runs i get a "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()" error every single time. Logging in and kicking the application off manually then works.

As stated, this is set to run as an admin account and I have given the account full control in security. I DO NOT have the "run only if logged in" checked, nor do i have it set to ONLY run when idle.

From what i know, the default timeout of a web request is 100,000 ms or 100 seconds. This task gets a timeout well before that limit is reached. Just before the code that is shown, i check to confirm my session is still valid and renew my session if it is not. This timeout ALWAYS happens on the first report attempting to be downloaded but when running manually I am able to download around 25 reports in under 2 minutes.

Any ideas?

Comment: ... have you tried expanding the timeout?

Comment: I've tried multiple different time outs, the timeout occurs well before the limit is reached in all cases.

Comment: Wait, it gives you a timeout error when you haven't reached a time out? Maybe you need to add a keep alive.

Comment: KeepAlive has a default value of True. I'll try adding that in though.

Comment: I have no idea if that is the problem but I always add a keep alive value of 300 when doing this type of work: `request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300")`. Also have you tried using a web debugging proxy like Telerik Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler to see what is actually happening on the server?

Comment: I feel like there is something going on server side as well. I think you need to watch the packets going back and forth to see the activity (I like wireshark) or as @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo suggested.

Comment: I'll need to wait until later tonight to test keep alive values as this server is used quite frequently throughout the day and I can't have people blocked from it for an extended period of time. I do have a question about Fiddler and Wireshark. Are you required to run them on the server while the application is running so it can trace packets? If so i don't think this will help as i have a 100% success rate of being logged in and the application working. It's only when no users are connected that problems occur.

Comment: Is there a proxy involved with the requests somewhere that turns off when you logout?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Awesome suggestion! We use an internet security web proxy that works via Single Sign On for users. Basically the tool pulls the users network credentials any time they try and access a site behind the scenes before either allowing or blocking the traffic. The issue was once the admin account was disconnected, this web proxy would attempt to gather credentials from a logged in user but would find nothing. The request would then be denied. This is why any user being logged in worked but it failed every other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my previous comment, it would appear there is a proxy involved that requires the user to be logged in for the request to succeed.

Your response:

> We use an internet security web proxy that works via Single Sign On for users. Basically the tool pulls the users network credentials any time they try and access a site behind the scenes before either allowing or blocking the traffic. The issue was once the admin account was disconnected, this web proxy would attempt to gather credentials from a logged in user but would find nothing. The request would then be denied. This is why any user being logged in worked but it failed every other time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "the answer" but I created a rather crude `HttpWebRequest` test app and set it up to run as another user who is not logged in on Windows 7 (Sorry I don't have access to a server atm). The test worked flawlessly every way that I tried it. Maybe it is because Windows 7 does things differently than (which operating system are you trying to get this to work on?) or maybe it is actually something in your code that is causing the issue. Since this code worked for me I would suggest you try it and at least eliminate your code as being the problem.

Create a new vb.net app and make sure to remove all forms and create a module (Module1) and slap this code in there:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Const sUserAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
    Const sMainURL As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
    Private gsLogFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "logfile.txt")

    Sub Main()
        StartScrape()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartScrape()
        Try
            GetMethod(sMainURL)
            SaveTextToFile("Finished", gsLogFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            SaveTextToFile("Error: " & ex.Message, gsLogFile)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMethod(ByVal sPage As String) As Boolean
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
        Dim stw As StreamReader
        Dim bReturn As Boolean = True

        Try
            req = HttpWebRequest.Create(sPage)
            req.Method = "GET"
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = False
            req.UserAgent = sUserAgent
            req.Accept = "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5")
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
            req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300")

            resp = req.GetResponse        ' Get the response from the server 

            If req.HaveResponse Then
                resp = req.GetResponse        ' Get the response from the server 
                stw = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream)
                stw.ReadToEnd()    ' Read the response from the server, but we do not save it
            Else
                SaveTextToFile("No response received from host " & sPage, gsLogFile)
                bReturn = False
            End If
        Catch exc As WebException
            SaveTextToFile("Network Error: " & exc.Message.ToString & " Status Code: " & exc.Status.ToString & " from " & sPage, gsLogFile)
            bReturn = False
        End Try

        Return bReturn
    End Function

    Public Function SaveTextToFile(ByVal strData As String, ByVal FullPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim bAns As Boolean = False
        Dim objReader As IO.StreamWriter

        Try
            objReader = New IO.StreamWriter(FullPath, System.IO.File.Exists(FullPath))
            objReader.Write(Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") & " - " & strData)
            objReader.Close()
            bAns = True
        Catch Ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return bAns
    End Function
End Module
```

A log file `logfile.txt` will be created in the same directory as the exe when it is finished. If there is an error it will be logged to the file and at the end it will say "Finished" with a timestamp. I ran it a few different ways with different options in task scheduler and every time I just had one log entry that says "Finished". Please report your results if you decide to test this as if this test fails I would definitely say there is a problem with your scheduled task.

Comment: I'll give this a swing tomorrow. I've thrown my request into a While with a retry bool = to False. If i catch a timeout i set retry = True and increase a counter. On the third failure i accept the timeout and send myself an error email. I log each failure (with the number) as well as the final failure with time and date stamps. Will edit my original post with my changes and log file dump.